# What is the best practice for creating a class to communicate with an external API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I need to build a class that will be used to communicate with an external, legacy API from a Rails application. It is not a RESTful API and instead just has some arbitrary inputs that return structured JSON. This JSON then needs to be converted to ActiveRecord models (the key names in the JSON do not match the column names in the database) and saved.

My current thinking is as follows (assuming that our old application is called `Legacy`): a file at `lib/legacy/api.rb` with contents much like:

```
module Legacy
  class Api
    @@host = "https://api.legacy.com.au"

    def get_listings
      self.get_path("get_places")
    end

    protected

      def get_path(path)
        uri = URI.parse(@@host + "/#{path}"
        req = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        req.use_ssl = true
        res = req.get(uri.request_uri)
        self.parse_json(res.body)
      end

      def parse_json(response)
        ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
      end
  end
end
```

I would then expect to use the API in my code like `Legacy::Api.get_listings`.

What I am trying to work out is if this is the best practice, or if there is a better way to structure this kind of class. Furthermore, if this is the best way to make external calls to APIs.

Comment: You're just planning on reading all objects from this API, saving to db and forgetting about it? Or how will you exactly interact with API?

Comment: Yeah, it will only be one-way. The app will connect to the API once a day and persist new records, update existing and remove deleted records. It will never send data back to the legacy API.